# как почему репозиторий не отдаёт артефакты, при созданни jira плагина

Tags: maven, jira, artifactory

В общем JFrog artifactory подгрузил 902 артефакта, я настроил на закачку через репозиторий. Но он не закачивает либо не видит артефакты, я не совсем понял даже в чем проблема.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот настройки mavena  из файла **settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <username>${security.getCurrentUsername()}</username>
      <password>${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"AP2xgycfgk3BnuMXZNBWu9i5ZQx"}</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>${security.getCurrentUsername()}</username>
      <password>${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"AP2xgycfgk3BnuMXZNBWu9i5ZQx"}</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>libs-snapshot</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
      <id>libs-snapshot</id>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Воспользовался советом Sergi и получил результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я как заметил он почему то не качает и пытается взять данные из .m2 папочки

В общем попробовал новые настройки **settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
      <repository>
             <id>maven-public</id>
             <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/maven-public</url>
           <releases>
                 <enabled>true</enabled>
                 <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
               </releases>
          </repository>
      <repository>
             <id>maven-external</id>
             <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/maven-external</url>
       <releases>
                 <enabled>true</enabled>
                 <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
               </releases>
      </repository>
      <repository>
            <id>maven2</id>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/maven2/</url>
      <releases>
                 <enabled>true</enabled>
                 <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
              </releases>
          </repository>
          <repository>
             <id>public</id>
             <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/public/</url>
       <releases>
                 <enabled>true</enabled>
                 <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
               </releases>
          </repository>
       </repositories>
       <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
               <id>public</id>
               <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/public/</url>
         <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                 </releases>
       </pluginRepository>
       <pluginRepository>
            <id>maven2</id>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/maven2/</url>
      <releases>
                  <enabled>true</enabled>
                  <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
              </releases>
       </pluginRepository>
       <pluginRepository>
            <id>maven-external</id>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/maven-external</url>
      <releases>
                 <enabled>true</enabled>
                 <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
              </releases>
       </pluginRepository>
       <pluginRepository>
            <id>maven-public</id>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/maven-public</url>
      <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
              </releases>
       </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  </settings>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

НО он почему-то все равно пытается скачать в репозитории lib-realease ?????

Comment: Atlassian SDK использует свою версию Maven'а, и, соответсвенно, свои глобальные настройки (D:\atlassian-plugin...\apache-maven..\conf\settings.xml).  Похоже, что ошибка или в этом файле, или происходит, когда Maven объединяет глобальные и пользовательские настройки.  Ошибка говорит, что у вас есть несколько pluginRepository с одинаковым id  в профиле defaultProfile.  Я бы начал смотреть оттуда

Comment: А вы, случайно, не удалили atlassian-public репозиторий из settings.xml Maven'а из D:\arlassian-plugin...? По идее, com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:6.3.1, должен браться из этого репозитория.  А ещё, проверьте, задана ли у вас переменная среды ATLAS_HOME

Comment: да, задана, но я как заметил он почему то не качает и пытается взять данные из .m2 папочки :3

Comment: еще я создал setting.xml с названием на репозиториев в которых хранятся артефакты и снова нет ни какого результата.

Comment: Попробуйте удалить ваш локальный maven репозиторий (%USERPROFILE%\.m2\repository) и запустить заново. Если не поможет, то покажите лог мавена

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем спасибо **Sergi** ваша поддержка и действия мне очень сильно помогли.

Теперь я расскажу как я это реализовал :3

В общем устанавливаем JFrog Artifactory, с сайта скачиваем бесплатную версию, в папке bin запускаем как на видео по установке либо artifactory-service.exe либо installService.bat (не помню точно, ибо не критично) в cmd можно воспользоваться командой

```
artifactory-service.exe help
```

после установки можно воспользоваться командой (что бы посмотреть результат)

```
sc query Artifactory
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

команды sc start Artifactory, sc stop Artifactory возможно вам потребуються по этому советую их запомнить.

После того как установили создаём Remote Repository (Generic) с нужными для нас адресами репозиториев, Remote Repository это ленивый репозиторий по этому он начнет закачку только после запроса !! Закачивает артефакты (если вы не меняли настройки) в папку {юзер наме}/.m2 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После установки и настройки JFroga, устанавливаем Atlassian-SDK. Ставим все по инструкции там все без эксцессов. Идем в папку atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.3.6\apache-maven-3.2.1\conf открываем файл **settings.xml** прописываем адреса наших ленивых репозиториев :3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>maven-public</id>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/maven-public</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
         <id>maven-external</id>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/maven-external</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>maven2</id>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/maven2/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>public</id>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/public/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>public</id>
              <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/public/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>maven2</id>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/maven2/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>maven-external</id>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/maven-external</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>maven-public</id>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/maven-public</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

в cmd запускаем команду (желательно в новой папке) atlas-create-jira-plugin
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

BUILD SUCCESS ураа ))

*ВАЖНО если у вас при сборке и погрузке зависимостей и артефактов результат был BUILD FAILURE возможно проблемма в settings.xml и вы поменяли настройки сетинга то ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО переименуйте либо удалите  папку {юзер наме}/.m2 ибо даже с измененными настройками сетинга он обращаеться к папку {юзер наме}/.m2 и смотрит там (даже если папка пустая) а не во внешних(http) репозиториях*